# Syntax error running shutter and apt. Suspect perl has something to do with it

Tags: apt, dpkg, 17.04, perl, shutter

I am getting a really strange error running `apt` and some other programs. I think it may have something to do with `perl`.

I discovered the issue trying to run shutter:

```
$ shutter
syntax error at /usr/bin/shutter line 0, near "$!;"
syntax error at /usr/bin/shutter line 0, near "q/etc/perl/sitecustomize.pl}"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/shutter line 29.
```

I thought the issue was with Shutter, but when I tried to run `apt upgrade` to update it, I received the same errors (but this time in various `dpkg` scripts):

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-35 linux-headers-4.10.0-35-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-37
  linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
syntax error at /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure line 0, near "$!;"
syntax error at /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure line 0, near "q/etc/perl/sitecustomize.pl}"
syntax error at /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure line 17, near "}"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line {} string starting on line 7)
syntax error at /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure line 18, near "$@) "
syntax error at /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure line 20, near "0;"
syntax error at /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure line 30, near "0;"
Execution of /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure aborted due to compilation errors.
Setting up mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 0, near "$!;"
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 0, near "q/etc/perl/sitecustomize.pl}"
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 15, near "022)"
syntax error at /usr/sbin/update-mime line 22, near "0;"
Execution of /usr/sbin/update-mime aborted due to compilation errors.
dpkg: error processing package mime-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mime-support
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Searching for `syntax error near "$!;"` and `syntax error near "q/etc/perl/sitecustomize.pl}"` has yielded nothing so far. I am on Ubuntu 17.04.

Grep tells me that neither of those strings are actually in the files mentioned so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There's a bug report [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2016-June/286136.html) so you might need to file one

Comment: What do you have on line 0?